# In an if/else if statement, the variable is being locked into the first option. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

This is my general code (in JavaScript):

```
let x = Math.floor(Math.random()×6)+1);

if (x=1){
   do this
} else if (x=2){
   do that
} else if.... and so on.
```

Whenever I test this code in a browser, only actions that could happen in the {do this} section happen. x is being locked as 1, even though it is meant to be a fair 6 sided die. Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: you set x equal to 1 each time. 1 is truthy, so it passes the first conditional via the leaky assignment evaluating out to 1.

Comment: `==` and `===` are comparison. `=` is assignment

Comment: wouldn't that eliminate the ability for it to be variable, though? does that not just lock x in as 1?

Comment: thanks @j08691 that worked.

Comment: Just checking, are you using `×` on the first line, or `*`?

Comment: I love how fast this community gives answers. awesome

Comment: @DylanK25_ Welcome to StackOverflow, please go through the rules and format for **asking or answering** here. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 2):

The `=` operator in JavaScript is for assignment. `x=1` will always return `true` because that is an assignment that will never fail. To test for equality use `==` ([equality with conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality)) or `===` ([strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity)).

Answer (score 0):

You have your if (x=1) assigning the value of 1 to x, rather than checking if it's equal to it. This results in it always returning TRUE. Using a pair of == (or ===) will solve this.